# How to implement tagged unions consistently across multiple platforms

Tags: c, enums, clang, unions

I'd like to write some code in a way that gives autocompletion and doxygen a bit more to work with.  I also want to keep things small to target small devices.  And I'd like to be able to compile on PC to create applications that communicate with those devices, defining some of these structures only once.

https://github.com/drbartling/c_static_asserts/actions/runs/5136876848/jobs/9244193331

Things were working fine until I tried clang on Windows, and here my enums are larger than expected and I can't specify 0-sized arrays.  According to various questions and docs, it seems like `__attribute__((packed))` is what I want, but that's not working with clang on windows.

```
#include "static_assert.h"

#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct __attribute__((packed)) {
    int8_t  small_num;
    int32_t big_num;
    int16_t med_num;
} my_struct_t;
STATIC_ASSERT_TYPE_SIZE(my_struct_t, 7);
STATIC_ASSERT_MEMBER_OFFSET(my_struct_t, big_num, 1);
STATIC_ASSERT_MEMBER_OFFSET(my_struct_t, med_num, 5);

typedef enum __attribute__((packed)) {
    fruit,
    vegetable,
} union_tag_t;
STATIC_ASSERT_TYPE_SIZE(union_tag_t, 1);

typedef enum __attribute__((packed)) {
    apple,
    pear,
    banana,
} tasty_fruit_t;
STATIC_ASSERT_TYPE_SIZE(tasty_fruit_t, 1);

typedef struct __attribute__((packed)) {
    int8_t empty[0]; // Empty array for zero size. Vegetables are not tasty /s
} tasty_vegetable_t;
STATIC_ASSERT_TYPE_SIZE(tasty_vegetable_t, 0);

typedef struct __attribute__((packed)) {
    union_tag_t tag;
    union {
        tasty_fruit_t     fruit;
        tasty_vegetable_t vegetable;
    };
} tasty_food_t;
STATIC_ASSERT_TYPE_SIZE(tasty_food_t, 2);

int
main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    printf("\r\n");
    printf("sizeof(my_struct_t): %d\r\n", (int)sizeof(my_struct_t));
    printf("Offset of big_num is: %d\r\n", (int)offsetof(my_struct_t, big_num));
    printf("Offset of med_num is: %d\r\n", (int)offsetof(my_struct_t, med_num));

    printf("sizeof(union_tag_t): %d\r\n", (int)sizeof(union_tag_t));
    printf("sizeof(tasty_fruit_t): %d\r\n", (int)sizeof(tasty_fruit_t));
    printf("sizeof(tasty_vegetable_t): %d\r\n", (int)sizeof(tasty_vegetable_t));
    printf("sizeof(tasty_food_t): %d\r\n", (int)sizeof(tasty_food_t));

    tasty_food_t my_food = {.tag = fruit, .fruit = apple};
    // tasty_food_t my_food = {.tag = vegetable};

    if (fruit == my_food.tag) {
        tasty_fruit_t my_fruit = my_food.fruit;
        printf("My Fruit number is %d", (int)my_fruit);
    } else {
        printf("My food is not tasty");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

I get this error:

> main.c:19:1: error: static assertion failed due to requirement !(sizeof(union_tag_t) > 1)': union_tag_t is larger than 1 bytes

It would also be nice to have an example that works well with MSVC, but that's less important to me.

Comment: Any time you communicate between different operating systems or architectures, you need a serialization protocol, you can't just pass binary data directly.

Comment: "across multiple platform"?  Don't use the `_t` suffix - that's [reserved by POSIX](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799.2018edition/functions/V2_chap02.html#tag_15_02_02).

Comment: Clang has a `-fshort-enums` option. You may want to give that a try.

Comment: @AndrewHenle Noted, that's a bad habit that I can kick.

Comment: @user3386109 I did give that a go and got the same results.